# How to create native ARM executables on macOS using GHC/stack

Tags: macos, haskell, arm, haskell-stack

GHC now ([since 8.10.5](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/blog/20210605-ghc-8.10.5-released.html)) supports producing ARM code on macOS.

What flags or options in GHC or Stack do I need to use in order for it to produce ARM executables?

Context: I have an Apple silicon Mac. It can run `x86_64` code via Rosetta but it can also run native ARM code.

Comment: I can't see if you need to cross-compile. In that case, you might want to look at [how to build a cross-compiling GHC](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/building/cross-compiling).

Comment: @chi yeah I guess it is cross-compiling in a sense. I'm running GHC via emulated x86_64 and want to target the native ARM architecture of my Mac now that according to release notes GHC should support this.

Comment: Cross-compiling is notoriously difficult on GHC. Refactoring work is underway to address this, but it won't be a quick fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will avoid discussing cross-compilation, since I don't think it is necessary.

For versions below GHC 9.2, you need to pass `-fllvm` in `ghc-options`. This is because GHC didn't include a Native Code Generator for the M1 yet. The Stack guide has [a section on using ghc-options](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#ghc-options). You can set them globally, or you can set them for a narrower scope. You can try `stack repl --resolver lts-19.1 --ghc-options -fllvm` in your project to see if its dependencies are compatible with GHC 9.0.2, which is what LTS 19.1 uses.

For versions GHC 9.2+, GHC has a Native Code Generator such that it can compile for the M1 without LLVM. This should just work, with no need to pass any special `ghc-options`.

Make sure you are using Stack v2.7.5+, because this version added support for installing GHC on macOS aarch64 (which is what the M1 is). See [the changelog](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/ChangeLog.md#v275---2022-03-06). You can upgrade Stack using `stack upgrade`.

Stack v2.7.5 hasn't been tested with versions above GHC 9.0 though, so you may want to use Cabal instead, if you choose to use GHC 9.2+. See this snippet:

```
$ stack repl --compiler ghc-9.2.2
Stack has not been tested with GHC versions above 9.0, and using 9.2.2, this may fail
```

Comment: One should also use system GHC for this, right? Over here `~/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-9.2.2/lib/ghc-9.2.2/bin/ghc-9.2.2` is an `x86_64` executable while `~/.ghcup/ghc/9.2.2/lib/ghc-9.2.2/bin/ghc-9.2.2` is `arm64`

Comment: I have also seen the recommendation to use the system GHC, but I think it is because it was needed *before* Stack 2.7.5 was released. The path you pasted contains `x86_64`. But you're not on that architecture, and we're trying to avoid emulation, so that path shouldn't be downloaded/needed in the first place. The new Stack release should download to a different directory in `~/.stack/programs`, maybe called something like `aarch64-osx`. So maybe try wiping `~/.stack/programs`. If the new Stack downloads anything related to `x86_64`, I think it must be a bug.

Comment: I wiped `~/.stack/programs` as you suggested and on the next `stack test` of my project it redownloaded GHC for `x86_64` again.
I don't think it's a bug. Actually if it only downloaded an ARM GHC that won't cross-compile to Intel, then it would create ARM-only executables that not all Macs could run and if you want to create apps that wouldn't be useful.